# How to filter a different item value of two array of objects in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filtering, difference

I'm trying to get **single object with different item** based by the `id` from compared result of two array of objects.

Here's the case:

#### First Array

```
[
    {
        "id": "792657571767910421",
        "type": 0,
        "allow": "0",
        "deny": "0"
    },
    {
      "id": "1020443938668171294",
      "type": 0,
      "allow": "0",
      "deny": "377959221312"
    },
    {
      "id": "791708642813411358",
      "type": 0,
      "allow": "0",
      "deny": "0"
    }
]
```

#### Second Array

```
[
    {
      "id": "792657571767910421",
      "type": 0,
      "allow": "1024",
      "deny": "0"
    },
    {
      "id": "1020443938668171294",
      "type": 0,
      "allow": "0",
      "deny": "377959221312"
    },
    {
      "id": "791708642813411358",
      "type": 0,
      "allow": "0",
      "deny": "0"
    },
]
```

#### Expected Output

```
[
    {
      "id": "792657571767910421",
      "type": 0,
      "allow": "1024",
      "deny": "0"
    },
]
```

#### Different value

```
// First array
{
    "allow": "0"
}

// Second array
{
    "allow": "1024"
}
```

Can anyone help me? Thank you.

Comment: And have you tried anything?

Comment: Please post the broken JavaScript as a [mcve] so we can fix it, we do not write code (or at least we shouldn't) if there's no effort on your side.

Comment: there are 2 arrays . and your expected result is the second array . then what is the logic to filter them . on which basis you wanna filter them . you just simply expect your output as the second array

Comment: I've tried to find it like this: `arr1.filter((item) => !arr2.some((i) => i.allow === item.allow))` but it return all the items.

Comment: Are the arrays _symmetric_? meaning that objects must correspond in their position (index) in each array?  Are objects at different indices ever compared?  (if you sort them by id, are they symmetric?)  or are we always comparing first[i] to second[i]?  In which case you'll just need to look for a [_deepEqual_ implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183/how-to-determine-equality-for-two-javascript-objects).  Comparing `JSON.stringify`'ed versions of the objects can work in a pinch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use custom filter logic:

#### Logic:

- Loop over `arr2` or the array you need output from.
- Test items with `param2`. On match:

  - Loop over `arr1` or the other array.
  - Find the object with same ID.
  - On finding,

    - Test item with `param1`. Return test value.
  - Else return false

```js
function filter(arr1, arr2, param1, param2) {
  const test = (param, item) =>
    Object
      .entries(param)
      .every(([k, v]) => item[k] === v)

  return arr2.filter((itemB) => {
    if (test(param2, itemB)) {
      const itemA = arr1.find(({id}) => id === itemB.id)
      return !!itemA ? test(param1, itemA) : false
    }
    return false
  })
}

const arr1 = [{"id": "792657571767910421","type": 0,"allow": "0","deny": "0"},{"id": "1020443938668171294","type": 0,"allow": "0","deny": "377959221312"},{"id": "791708642813411358","type": 0,"allow": "0","deny": "0"}]
const arr2 = [{"id": "792657571767910421","type": 0,"allow": "1024","deny": "0"},{"id": "1020443938668171294","type": 0,"allow": "0","deny": "377959221312"},{"id": "791708642813411358","type": 0,"allow": "0","deny": "0"},]

const param1 = {"allow": "0"}
const param2 = {"allow": "1024"}

console.log(filter(arr1, arr2, param1, param2))
```